# Check if an object is empty in mapbasic

Tags: mapinfo, sql, mapbasic

I have mapbasic code that manipulates the obj-column in a point-table. Some rows doesn't have any geometry so the obj-column is empty.  My question is how to check if  there is no object?

All the methods i found in the mapbasic-reference that givs information about the obj-column, like ObjectInfo(), try to access the object which givs an error since there is none.

Is there any way to use SQL to select the rows with non empty obj-columns?

Regards

Answer (score 6):

- Query For Selecting row(s) without object :

> ```
>     Select * from 'MYTABLE' where not obj into MYTABLE_NO_MAP_OBJECT   
>     Browse * From MYTABLE_NO_MAP_OBJECT
> ```

- Query For Selecting row(s) with object :

> ```
>      Select * from MYTABLE where obj into MYTABLE_MAP_OBJECT
>      Browse * From MYTABLE_MAP_OBJECT
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative if you loop a table in MapBasic code:

```
dim a as alias
dim o as object
dim t as string

t = "MyTable"
a = t + ".obj"

fetch first from t
do while not EOT (t)
  if a then 
    o = a
    ' Do something with o
  end if
  fetch next from t
loop
```

Answer (score 0):

use this query in MapInfo SQL , and you will get the result

[image]

Comment: 1- That's very old question.2-  Your answer is very short.

Comment: simple  and short